# elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Invalid or missing tagline (OpenSearch)

Tags: java, opensearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

After migrating to AWS OpenSearch from Elasticsearch we get the following error when calling OpenSearch via the `Elasticsearch-Rest-High-Level-Client`:

```
elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Invalid or missing tagline [The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the version of the `Elasticsearch-Rest-High-Level-Client` was too new. We used the client version `7.15.0` with OpenSearch `1.0`. We downgraded the client to `7.10.2` and it worked again.

Also using the `OpenSearch-Rest-High-Level-Client` in version `1.0` worked, too.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issue.
Downgrading version of Elasticsearch-Rest-High-Level-Client to 7.10.2 worked for me.