# Move from Elasticsearch (beyond version 7.10.2) to AWS OpenSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

The migration from Elasticsearch up to version 7.10.2 seems easy, basically we have to upload the snapshot to S3 and restore snapshot on Opensearch, following the steps described in [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/migration.html)

The problem is that I am using Elasticsearch version 7.17.0 (ECE platform), and snapshots taken beyond Elasticsearch 7.10.2 are not yet compatible with OpenSearch 1.0.0

So apparently the way to go would be to use Reindex API from OpenSearch, setting a source index and a destination index, according to [this article](https://opster.com/guides/opensearch/opensearch-basics/how-to-migrate-from-es-to-os-for-versions-after-7-10/#Can-the-7.11+-versions-be-migrated-to-OpenSearch) (not official AWS documentation).

So, is that the way to go, even for large datasets ? Are there other ways ?

The steps to take for this migration are well described in that non-official AWS article ?

Indices in cold tier in Elasticsearch would to go indices in cold storage in OpenSearch ?

Thank you in advance. All help/opinions around this topic (including comparisons between Elasticsearch Vs. AWS OpenSearch) are welcome.

I uploaded snapshot to S3 and tried to restore (unsuccessfully) snapshot in Opensearch, according to [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/migration.html) I got the same issue highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216176/elasticsearch-elasticsearchexception-invalid-or-missing-tagline-opensearch).

Comment: Correction: 7.10.2 not 7.12.0

Comment: @amsh I can answer the question partially. Please see below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I posted my question, I got more context and new insights, so I can answer the question partially and explain why.

**GENERAL CONTEXT:**

Since Opensearch forked out from the opensource Elasticsearch in 2021, there have been more than 10 times more Gitbub contributions to Elasticsearch than to Opensearch; with only 100 contributors to Opensearch, compared to 2000 contributors to Elasticsearch.

This doesn't mean ES is better than OS, but it has more features than OS, the question is: Are those new features needed ? In my experience, not necessarily in many use cases at the enterprise level. The downside of ES is that it depends on AWS or other cloud providers for backend services, infrastructure, storage, snapshot repository.

**ANSWER:**

Anyway, both services have diverged so much that they are have become incompatible, and migrating the whole code configuration from one to another is a code refactor, although the _reindex API from both are similar. That being said, the standard ways to transfer the data are the following:

**Option 1:** Reindex API (Reindexing essentially rebuilds the index from scratch, and it can be more resource intensive to run):

- ES to OS: Use the [ES reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)
- OS to ES: Use the [OS reindex
  API](https://opensearch.org/docs/1.2/opensearch/reindex-data/)

Note: The reindex API payload of ES and OS are the same:

POST _reindex

```
{
   "source":{
      "index":"source"
   },
   "dest":{
      "index":"destination"
   }
}
```

**Option 2:** Logstash or other 3rd party pipeline (more scalable but requires additional configuration):

Works from ES to OS - or from OS to ES

Logstash, can be used to stream data from/to your Elasticsearch cluster from/to an AWS OpenSearch domain (or any other data destination).